# Is this an actual shortcut for a Java Lazy-Getter

Tags: java, lazy-loading, lazy-evaluation, getter, lazy-initialization

The following is less a question than a request for evaluation.

So you will most likely be familiar with the following pattern of a lazy getter.

```
private Object obj;

public Object getObject() {
 if(obj==null) {
  obj = new Object();
 }
 return obj;
}
```

That code

- is long
- requires a class variable
- requires some logic inside the getter

So recently a colleague and I came up with the following interface (simplified):

```
public interface LazyGetterSupport {

default Object get(Supplier<Object> impl) {
    String key = impl.getClass().getName();
    Object retVal;
    if ((retVal = getInstanceCache().get(key)) == null) {
        retVal = impl.get();
        getInstanceCache().put(key, retVal);
    }
    return retVal;
}

Map<String, Object> getInstanceCache();
}
```

Sidenote: Not using HashMap#computeIfAbsent bc of [Bug-8071667](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8071667)

That Interface is then implemented by the class that you want to use lazy getters in. You need to provide an implementation of `getInstanceCache()` as follows:

```
private Map<String, Object> instanceCache;

@Override
public Map<String, Object> getInstanceCache() {
    if (instanceCache == null) {
        instanceCache = new HashMap<>();
    }
    return instanceCache;
}
```

But given that you can start rewriting all other lazy getters in that class (and subclasses) like this:

```
public Object getObject() {
    return get(Objetct::new);
}
```

This works because the key we get by using `impl.getClass().getName();` inside our Interface will actually always be unique for every lambda we use inside implementations of its get-method. Yet it will stay the same for each call-site for at least the life duration of our VM.

Benefits are obvious. We no longer have to create a class-variable for every lazy-getter and the getter themselves become shorter. It may not be a world of a difference, but in our use-case we often have classes with 20+ Lazy Getters for UI Elements. That is where this new technique comes to shine.

I would love to know your thoughts on this approach and whether you have any concerns towards using this in production.

Comment: This is more of a [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) question.

Comment: Not that the `computeIfAbsent` bug you linked to is marked **Resolution: Fixed**

Comment: Use computeIfAbsent. The bug is irrelevant to this use case.

Comment: The bug is still relevant to us as we're stuck to JDK8 for now. Will change with the next major release.

Comment: Using `ConcurrentHashMap` would make your code thread-safe and bypass the bug. I see very little use for the lazy getter pattern in general, but if you say it's the bee's knees for UI elements, I'll take your word for it...for now.

Comment: @Lukas again, the bug is not relevant to your use case. Using compute* should never have side effects, especially so for ConcurrentHashMap, but nevertheless the same holds true for a HashMap.

Comment: @xTrollxDudex We were using compute* in our initial attempt. But for some reason it would then compute the supplier every single time and never actually work in a lazy manner. Let's not look into this too deeply, it is fixed now anyway and is irrelevant to my point. I shouldnt have brought it up inside the question in the first place, my bad.

Comment: I'm with @Kayaman on this one. I don't get why you'd want UI elements to pop up at the last minute.

Answer (score 5):

Or you could simply use [`@Getter(lazy=true)`](https://projectlombok.org/features/GetterLazy) from [Project Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/).

Comment: Did not know how much awesome Lombok could do. Will look into that, thanks.

Comment: @Lukas I was sceptical about Lombok for a very long time. But after a colleage almost forced me using it in one of the projects, I'm a big fan.

Answer (score 2):

Your cache is per class which doesn't feel future proof to me. If you had some generic `Supplier` that was used multiple times then using the `Class` as the cache key wouldn't work. I'd just store a reference on a `LazyValue` which you can use and cache however you like. Here's a thread safe implementation:

```
public class LazyValue<T> {
    private AtomicReference<T> reference = new AtomicReference<>();
    private final Supplier<T> supplier;

    public LazyValue(Supplier supplier) { this.supplier = supplier; }

    public T get() {
        T t = reference.get();
        if (t == null) {
            synchronized (reference) {
                t = reference.get();
                if (t == null) {
                    t = supplier.get();
                    reference.set(t);
                }
            }
        }
        return t;
    }  
}

public class MyBean {
    private LazyValue<Object> lazyObject = new LazyValue(Object::new);
    public Object getObject() {
        return lazyObject.get();
    }
}
```

Comment: Makes a lot of sense, but has the downside of forcing us to deal with LazyValue's all over the place. My solution avoids that wrapper and therefore works better when adding it to legacy code since we do not have to rewrite anything outside the getter.

Comment: Seems much cleaner that your `getInstanceCache()` and implementing an interface

Answer (score 1):

Looks interesting, but you replaced a bunch of member variables with a Hashmap. While this works, it increases the memory usage of your class, and adds O(1) overhead to member access. Synchronizing the lazy getter method is not enough, you need to synchronize on the HashMap, adding keys concurrently will break something. In the traditional lazy getter, synchronizing on the one attribute is enough. Here, if you concurrently access different attributes they have to wait on each other.

And in your use case, I really wonder why one would need lazy getters for UI elements.

Comment: We're using Swing. For our UIs we frequently use the lazy pattern for elements such as JTextFields.

Comment: @Lukas ... that are not visible immediately?

Comment: I am actually not sure why our UI elements are being lazy loaded now that I think about it. That's just the way it has been done. 
But if I neglect a lazy getter, where do I put the initialization code? Like for example I have some stuff I want to do with my JLabel that I can not do with its constructor. Technically I could have one central initialize method for the entire class but that does not seem practical..

Comment: @Lukas in the best case it's because you have a very complicated UI and it would take unnecessarily long to initialize it fully at the beginning, and the design isn't modularized enough that you could initialize it in "screens" or "modules" or so. In a very common case it's because someone saw the pattern being used (whether useful or not), didn't understand why it was used and now propagates the [cargo cult](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) himself. Why doesn't an init method for a class seem practical? Because of the class design or other reasons?

Comment: @Lukas What I do when I design GUIs is group UI elements in subclasses of JPanel (subclassing may not be the correct approach, but you can have different classes being responsible for different parts of the UI) and then, yes, initialize the components in central initialize methods. You can of course still have small functions that initialize only certain components, and call those somewhere central. I suppose the same happens with your getters now.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. There certainly appears to be some Cargo Cult involved. I'll talk about that with my colleague and take your proposals in consideration when we decide on how to proceed with our boilerplate code.

Answer (score 1):

```
Object o;
public Object getInstance() {
    return o == null ? (o = new Object()) : o;
}
```

No need for a fancy HashMap, just convert "long" 4 lines of code into 1.

Comment: But this doesn't have any of the unnecessary complexity and overengineering present in the solution with `Suppliers` and `Support` interfaces and the claimed huge benefits of this stupid pattern. How dare you write code that's simple and instantly understandable.

Comment: Opinions are illegal, begone!

Comment: Very true. And curly braces are not required either in my first example. Hard to say whether the overhead of the Map makes any sense.

Answer (score 0):

You could also allow the client to actually set a property.

```
interface LazyGetterSupport<T> {
    T get();

    static <T> LazyGetterSupport<T> of(T value, Supplier<T> create, Consumer<T> store) {
        T result = value;
        if (result == null) {
            result = create.get();
            store.accept(result);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

which you could call using

```
class Client {
    Object field;
    void getField() {
        LazyGetterSupport.of(field, Object::new, o -> field = o).get();
    }
}
```